# How do I clear this VBA Error when using Match Function

Tags: excel, vba, match, userform

I have written a VBA script that adds the information selected in a userform to a specific row in a spreadsheet.

Now I'm trying to create a button that allows for users to edit the userform. I initially used the code

```
Dim targetrow As Integer

'Case select being the drop-down box where users select the case number

'Tracker is the spreadsheet and Case_ID is the column that contains the case ID

targetrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Case_Select, Sheets("Tracker").Range("Case_ID"), 0)

MsgBox targetrow

'Just want to test and display the number

End Sub
```

But I got an error,

> "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"

I did some research and everyone was saying to remove the worksheetfunction and just use match, which I did as shown here:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim targetrow As Integer

Dim case_id As Integer


targetrow = Application.Match(Case_Select, Sheets("Tracker").Range("Case_ID"), 0)


End Sub
```

However, now I'm getting a

> "Run-time error 13": Type Mismatch"

Not sure what is causing this or how to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Variant for `targetrow`, otherwise it can't handle the error value returned when `Application.Match` doesn't make a match.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim targetrow As Variant
    Dim case_id As Integer


    targetrow = Application.Match(Case_Select, Sheets("Tracker").Range("Case_ID"), 0)
    If Not IsError(targetrow) Then
        'got a match, and `targetrow` is the matched row
        Debug.Print "Matched on row# " & targetrow
    Else
        Debug.Print "No match" 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The error is gone, but no message is coming up, I had to add a "then" after the iserror(Targetrow), so I'm not sure if it's working or not. Any thoughts?

Comment: The output will be in the VBA Immediate pane (Ctrl+G in the VB editor)   I prefer that to constantly clicking OK in messageboxes